# Как добавить Genymotion Device Manager на панель? Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, genymotion

не могу найти  иконку Genymotion на панели,можно найти через Find Action.Как его добавить на панель?
[image: Панель без Genymotion]

[image: Поиск через Find Action]

Answer (score 2):

Для этого вам необходимо зайти в настройку: `View-Appearance` и там поставить галочку напротив пункта меню `Toolbar`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Дальше нажимаем правой кнопкой на пустое место на появившемся toolbar-e и выбираем `Customise Menus and Toolbars`. Там выбираем пункт `Main Toolbar` из списка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и дальше нажимаем сверху + при этом курсор должен стоять на пустом месте и выбираем `Add Action`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и все :) Но все действия выше нужно делать при условии что после добавления тулбара у вас там уже нету значка. Потому что у меня после установки данного плагина значок появился после перезагрузки IDE.

Comment: Посмотрел в настройках,там он отображается.Удалил->Добавил->Ничего

Comment: что вы удалили и добавили?

Comment: Genymotion уже там был,в Main toolbar,я его удалил и заново добавил

Comment: тогда попробуйте удалить сам плагин - перезагрузить студию - установить плагин - перезагрузить студию

Comment: сделал,тоже самое-не сработало.Может быть это из-за масштабирования win 10?

Comment: при чем здесь масштабирование, как оно влияет на поведение android studio и ее плагинов?)

Comment: Не знаю,недавно начал использовать win 10 и настраивал шрифты и т.д.

Comment: а сама IDE нормально работает с эмулятором?

Comment: Да,работает хорошо

Comment: попробуйте перейти в settings->other settings->genymotion и там указать папку где установлен genymotion

Comment: Там уже стоит путь